# 12V DC Power Supply Regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator

I'm doing up a Steadicam that takes power from a V mount battery and feeds it via a socket at the top to the camera and other devices and a socket at the bottom to the monitor and such.
  I've done all the work but have realised the the V mount puts out 14.5V and some of the kit wants 12V and could be a bit sensitive about the difference. I checked the battery and fully charged it puts out 15.5V and I'm draining it now to see if these is much difference when it's almost empty.
  So I need to open up the battery bracket I built and put something in there to regulate it to 12V. There's not too much room so I'm looking for something small, to be specific more flat than boxy.

So I've been a bit unclear, On a 12V regulated battery plate a 190Wh battery lasts about 3 hours when it's all rigged up.

As for the unregulated power out of my new plate it's at between 11-15.5V depending how full the battery is. Sorry for the confusion.

Any ideas or advice?

Comment: At the very least you need to specify the total required current across all your devices.

Comment: NoBody can design anything !! without specs for peak Current and voltage load regulation. then you need Pd and max T rise.

Comment: Hard to make any suggestion, because current consumption is not given. However, you can use a single L7812 regulator if the total current consumption is lower than 100mA. A proper heatsink is required if the total current consumption is higher than 100mA and lower than 300mA (Because dissipation rises to 1W). For higher than 300mA, don't even think about L7812, an SMPS is required instead.

Comment: What current? -

Comment: I'm not too up on the electrical side of this job, this is why I came here to ask. A 190Wh battery lasts about 3 hours I guess so I don't think the L7812 would do the job. I was trying to find one of the little regulator boxes off eBay but I checked the drained battery and it put out 11V, so 11-15.5V and that’s outside of the ranges specified for the little converters on line, they normally bottom out at about 14V and I'm not sure what happened if the battery can supply that.

Comment: I was locked out there for a while.

Comment: if the input can go under/over the output, you should use a buck boost switching power supply unit, which can be had for a few bucks on ebay/amazon

Comment: Like this one? http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-DC-Boost-Buck-Step-up-Step-down-Converter-2-15V-3-3V-12V-Power-Supply-Module-/282386508185?var=&hash=item41bf8c2999:m:mZjPUgi9gWJE_zZPmQ7r-Hg

Comment: 25% loss is best case not always typ. how cheap are you?

Comment: Money is not really a consideration. Is there another way of going about this that would be better?

Answer (score 1):

ok so 190Wh/3h/15V=4.2A and any LDO will drop Pd={15-12}* 4.2A = 12~13 watts of wasted heat.  N.G. either match the battery voltage to the load or match the load max PWM duty cycle to the battery voltage !!

a low loss 10A LC filter will smooth the V+ avg. Ie. SMPS load type servo motors.

are they BLDC or BDC? they should be N phase type with N>=3 for smoothest control.

ultra low loop ESR (+motorDCR) is essential for high torque servo well-damped position stabilizer with PID loop stabilizer or fuzzy logic feedback.

> Remember that motor torque is controlled by current sensing not battery voltage.

Comment: No that's a Gimbal I think you are thinking about, like the Ronin. A Steadicam dose the same job but it's compleatly mechanical. The battery plate is there for the camera, monitor, some other low power accessory's and counter weight. The only motors would be for the remote focus controller.

Comment: These V mount batteries are standard for filming, there what everything runs off so I have to stick with them.

Comment: ok then use whatever you need for DC-DC buck-boost converter at >90% to 95% efficiency, which cost more than 70-85% effic. and ... use very smooth bearings on inertial gyro.

Comment: Yeah, the bearings are powered by ham sandwiches, I think you still talking about a Gimbal not a Steadicam but I don't suppose it makes any difference. So do I understand that the buck booster will mean the battery lasts 25-30% less time?

Comment: yes Monday, efficiency loss means less battery life. I was thinking of GlideCam and Arri with mayo and no lettuce. lighter and more stable

Answer (score -1):

Given the possibly low headroom but also possibly significant current (you didn't spec this at all), I'd look to a buck switcher.  Those can inherently run with very little headroom, but are still efficient when the input voltage goes higher.

There are many many choices out there.  Take a look at the Microchip MCP16311 as one example.

Comment: the battery is 11-15V drained to full and the kit runs at about 60W.

Comment: @yadnom1973 Please add that vital information to your question.